# How to forcibly set focus on an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you forcibly set focus on an html element(input field) when there is another input field in the same web page (which gets loaded later) and steals the focus from the other input field? This 2nd input field is a part of an iFrame.

Both the input fields are independent (no one is a parent of the other), so I am not able to use event.stopPropagation() method here.

Comment: did you try to set it on $(document).ready or document.onload?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. The focus still goes away to the other input field.

Comment: just put the `.focus()` at the very bottom of your document ready function..

Answer (score 2):

Just steal it back using the `blur` event the first time it is blurred, and refocus it using `focus()`

```
$("#my-input").one("blur", function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kcuL1aec/

And yes, that is [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and not [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), so that it only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) function. Once the document has fully loaded simply use your favourite selection function to grab the html element and just do `element.focus()`

Comment: I had tried setting the focus with this function. The element has focus for a fraction of a second, and then the focus goes off on complete page load.